# R pulling out sub strings from vcf files

Tags: r, substring

I have data from VCF files (variant call format) which I would like to work with in R. The data look typically like this:

```
0/1:127,38:165:99:255,0,255
0/0:127,0:127:99:0,255,255
1/1:0,127:127:99:255,255,0
```

The information I need to pull out is (for the first line):

```
0/1,
127, and
38
```

For clarity: the information I would retrieve from the line two:

```
0/0,
127, and 
0
```

And from line three:

```
1/1,
0, and
127
```

(The remaining information in the string is of no interest for now.)

Could this be done in R?
I would be much obliged for feedback on this one.

Thanks.
S

Comment: how about using `y<-substring(x,1,9)` and then using `strsplit(y,":|,")` ?

Comment: Ah, I might be unclear here. I would need it like this:

Comment: Ah, I might be unclear here. For the first line I would need something like this: x<- '0/1', y<-127, and z<-38.  And the substring(x,1,9) does only occasionally extract all information. Sometimes I'd need substring(x,1,10).

Comment: In that case, you need to make the question more clear and provide reproducible example.

Comment: strsplit(y,":") alone did work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Replace colons with commas and then read it in using `read.table`:

```
read.table(text = gsub(":", ",", L), sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)[1:3]
```

giving:

```
   V1  V2  V3
1 0/1 127  38
2 0/0 127   0
3 1/1   0 127
```

**2)** An alternative would be `read.pattern` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com):

```
library(gsubfn)

read.pattern(text = L, pattern = "^(.*?):(.*?),(.*?):", as.is = TRUE)
```

giving the same result.  Here is a visualization of the regular expression.  The occurrences of `?` in the regular expression cause `.*` to match the shortest rather than longest string possible:

```
^(.*?):(.*?),(.*?):
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3UwpFOhegOPx9xRJ)

**Note:** We used this input data:

```
L <- "0/1:127,38:165:99:255,0,255
0/0:127,0:127:99:0,255,255
1/1:0,127:127:99:255,255,0"
```

Answer (score 1):

A different solution is to use [VariantAnnotation](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/VariantAnnotation.html); read the [vignette](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/VariantAnnotation/inst/doc/VariantAnnotation.pdf) and see `?readVcf` and be sure to use `ScanVcfParam()` to selectively read just those parts of the file you're interested in. Ask for more help on the Bioconductor [support forum](https://support.bioconductor.org) if this seems like a useful approach.